# Can you use linq to see if two IEnumerables of data contain any common entries?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

```
IEnumerable<fishbiscuits> a = GetFishBiscuits(0);
IEnumerable<fishbiscuits> b = GetFishBiscuits(1);

if ([any of the results in either list match])
{
 // Do something ie
 Console.WriteLine("I see both a and b love at least one of the same type of fish biscuit!");
}
```

Can you use linq to see if two IEnumerables of data contain any common entries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) and [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx):

```
bool anyCommonEntries = a.Intersect(b).Any();
```

Comment: Great, I was fiddling around with 'contains' :)

Comment: Understand that Intersect() uses the Equals() method found on all Objects; if the elements aren't built-in value types, strings, or IEquatable/IStructuralEquatable implementations, the runtime will resort to the default reference equality check from Object, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @KeithS: True, but you can workaround this, if necessary, by overriding `Equals`/`GetHashCode` on the objects themselves, or by passing a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the `Intersect` method.

Comment: Very true. I was just making sure OP knew that Intersect() by itself wouldn't be a silver bullet in most cases.

Comment: I made that exact mistake first time so thanks for pointing it out - I then changed my code to `GetFishBiscuits(0).select(c => c.uniqueID);` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Linq50()
{
    int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
    int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

    var commonNumbers = numbersA.Intersect(numbersB);

    Console.WriteLine("Common numbers shared by both arrays:");
    foreach (var n in commonNumbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

---

From 101 Linq Samples - [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#Intersect1)

[Msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136) for Intersect

[Extension Methods Roundup: Intersect, Union, AsNullable and GroupEvery](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2008/08/01/6463327.aspx)